# import class with pandas from file

Tags: importerror

I have two files:
main.py

```
from personal_function.Convert import cls_Convert

df_key = 'PERFIL'

a = cls_Convert(df_data_2)
a.convert_cat_to_num(df_key)
df_data_2 = a.df
```

personal_function/Convert.py

```
import pandas as pd

class cls_Convert:
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df = df

    # Mudar variavel categorica para numerica
    def convert_cat_to_num(self,df_key):
        self.df[df_key] = pd.factorize(self.df[df_key],sort=True)[0] + 1
        return self.df

    # Mudar variavel numerica para categorica
    def convert_num_to_cat(self,df_key,cat_bin,cat_label):
        self.df[df_key].replace(to_replace = cat_bin, value =cat_label, inplace=True)
        return self.df
```

however I get this error

ImportError: cannot import name 'cls_Convert' from 'personal_function.Convert'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use

```py
from os import getcwd
from sys import path
cwd = getcwd()
path.append(cwd)
```

than use the whole absolute path

Answer (score 0):

For a class or function to be visible outside of a package, it must be imported in the package's `__init__.py` file which is run when the package is imported from somewhere. All the variables, imports, method,  and classes defined in that `__init__.py` are then made visible to the package that was importing them. Take the below example:

example/example.py

```py
def visible():
    pass

def not_visible():
    pass
```

example/**init**.py

```py
from .ex import visible
```

main.py

```py
from example import visible
from example import not_visible # results in an error since it was not imported
                                # in the `example` package's `__init__.py` file.
```

To make your `Convert` class visible to the external `main.py` file, create the `__init__.py` for the package.

You can read more about python submoduling [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules)